# using email and username both as login in spring security plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using spring security plugin in my Grails application and i would like the users registered to login into the application with username or email address provided during the registration process.(just like fb)

I have already looked into the web and concerned Grails docs :::
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#4.1%20Person%20Class

but could not find any solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a spring-security point of view, what you should do is implement your own *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService*

```
public class MyUserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private AdminUserDao dao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    ... Here comes your logic to get your the user based on email or userid ...

    }
}
```

in your spring config you have to reference your UserDetails class:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserServiceImpl" />
</authentication-manager>
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything of recent about this. In later version of spring security / grails 3.2.8. Here is mine:

This is a service created in services. User email sits in a separate class outside of User hence the `attributes.email` check otherwise you could just do `User.findByUsernameOrEmail(username,username)`

So I have UserEmailUserService as a service:

```
package com.app.users

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException

class UserEmailUserService extends GormUserDetailsService{

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }

    @Transactional
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //enable login with either username or password
        User user = User.find {
            username == username || attributes.email == username
        }
        if (!user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)
        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.username, user.getPassword(),
                user.enabled, !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired, !user.accountLocked, getAuthorities(user.roles))
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities())
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return userDetails
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Set<Role> roles) {
       List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>()
       roles?.each { role ->
          authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.authority))
       }
       return authorities
   }
}
```

Then in `conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import com.app.users.UserEmailUserService

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
      userDetailsService(UserEmailUserService){
            grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
        }
}
```

Please note I called `user.roles` This is a custom call I made in user class. Since I have groups roles etc :

```
Set<Role> getRoles() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
}
```